# 2 files having the same name but different paths => vim thinks they are the same

Tags: vim

Say I am already editing one file :

```
/path_one/thisfile
```

And I want to edit an other file with the same name but in a different path :

```
/path_two/thisfile
```

The problem is that vim says it found a swap file by the name thisfile, so every time I want to edit 2 files with the same name, I have to press e before editing ...

Is there a way to fix this pesky behavior ?

Comment: What is the value of `:verbose set dir?`

Comment: @Peter It is `directory=.,~/tmp,/var/tmp,/tmp`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where the *swap file* is generated is controlled by the `'directory'` option (not very intuitive). Its `:help 'directory'` says:

> - The swap file will be created in the first directory where this is
>     possible.

Since you're using the default `'directory'` setting, you either

- don't have write permission to the file's directory, so it has to use a following entry in the option, or
- have the two directories linked to the same target

If it's the former, you can work around this by making Vim include the full path in the swap file name:

> - For Unix and Win32, if a directory ends in two path separators "//"
>     or "\", the swap file name will be built from the complete path to
>     the file with all path separators substituted to percent '%' signs.
>     This will ensure file name uniqueness in the preserve directory.
>     On Win32, when a separating comma is following, you must use "//",
>     since "\" will include the comma in the file name.

Therefore, try:

```
:set directory=.,~/tmp//,/var/tmp//,/tmp//
```