# VIM & NVIM have trouble differentiating file with same name but different very long path

Tags: vim, neovim

I have a two file with the same name & content like this.

```
// File 1
m/d/b/x/s/d/x/same_name.c
// File 2
p/t/k/x/d/x/same_name.c
```

When I have File 1 open in the buffer and try to open File 2, it always opens File 1. The only way to open File 2 is to do

```
:bw <Buffer number of File1>
```

- Tried this with/without plugins, on VIM and NVIM but I get the same result.
- This is not an issue when the path name is smaller.

I am guessing that this might be because of 'd/x/same_name.c' which is common on both long paths. (Or am completely wrong :D )

- What setting in vim/nvim can I use to control the path matching for buffers?
- Or is this a bug (I doubt it)

PS: I have already looked at this
[2 files having the same name but different paths => vim thinks they are the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21339087/2-files-having-the-same-name-but-different-paths-vim-thinks-they-are-the-same)
I am already using "//" in directory.

Comment: 1. Your example works as expected on the two Vims I have on this machine (8.0.1365 and 8.2.2681), with or without my config. 2. There is no `:dw` command, did you mean `:bw`? 3. Are you sure those files or some parent directory are not hard links? 4. No one knows "how many people use vim on large code based".

Comment: VIM is at 8.1.2269 and neovim is at 0.4.3

Comment: Okay. They turned out to be Hard Links. Just checked the inode number.